# VB.NET datagridview EndEdit decimales con "." (punto)

Tags: vb.net

Cuando cambia la celda de un `DataGridView` y pone por ejemplo "230.50" se transforma en "23050,00".

Estuve buscando la forma de tomar el valor en el evento `CellEndEdit` y hacer un `Replace(".",",")` pero no hay manera. Una vez que apreta enter la variable que guarda el valor de la celda borra el separador `"."` y convierte todo a entero (`23050`).

la columna en cuestión guarda un precio que se le carga a los vendedores a mano cuando alcanzan cierto objetivo de ventas. La columna **PREMIO** es de tipo DOUBLE con 2 decimales, y la base de datos esta en Access.

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: pregunta, en que tipo de dato se guarda la celda?? podes definir un poco mas lo que estas haciendo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si la columna en cuestión está destinada a almacenar valores de moneda, es mejor utilizar este tipo de datos ([Moneda ó Currency ó Decimal](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Tipos-de-datos-para-bases-de-datos-de-escritorio-de-Access-df2b83ba-cef6-436d-b679-3418f622e482)) en lugar de `Double`.

El error no se debe a ese detalle, que sólo pretende ser un consejo para una mejor programación.

El problema se debe a que las configuraciones regionales son distintas entre el sistema operativo y el usuario.

En este caso el sistema operativo espera que el usuario use la coma como separador decimal. Pero el usuario está colocando el punto.

Lo que podemos hacer, además de instruir adecuadamente a los usuarios, es ordenar a nuestro software, que corrija los datos que ellos introducen.

Podemos basarnos en un ejemplo de la [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellparsing.aspx) para realizar la siguiente solución:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellParsing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellParsing

    If e IsNot Nothing Then
        If Me.DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name.ToUpper = "PREMIO" Then                
            If e.Value IsNot Nothing Then
                Try
                    ' Obtiene el valor que introdujo el usuario '
                    Dim valor$ = e.Value.ToString

                    ' Reemplaza el punto por la coma, y convierte a Double '
                    ' Es muy importante aquí la conversión explícita, porque la implícita no funcionará '
                    e.Value = CDbl(valor.Replace(".", ","))

                    ' Indica que el evento ha sido manipulado por el programador '
                    e.ParsingApplied = True

                Catch ex As FormatException
                    ' En caso de error, no pudo haber corrección del valor '
                    e.ParsingApplied = False
                End Try
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! No conocía el evento CellParsing y es justamente lo que necesitaba.

Answer (score 0):

Mi sugerencia quizás te funcione, a mi en un proyecto grande me ha funcionado de manera correcta.
Como tenía problemas con los métodos de ingreso y los "formatos" de decimales lo que decidí es modificar esta configuración de cada terminal en el propio programa con la siguiente rutina:

```
 Public Sub CambiarRegistro()
    Dim regVersion = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(
              "Control Panel\\International", True)
    If regVersion Is Nothing Then
        ' Key doesn't exist; create it.
        MsgBox("NoExiste")
    End If

    Dim clave As String
    If regVersion IsNot Nothing Then
        clave = regVersion.GetValue("sDecimal")
        'MsgBox(clave)
        regVersion.SetValue("sDecimal", ".")
        regVersion.SetValue("sList", ",")
        regVersion.SetValue("sThousand", ",")
        regVersion.Close()
    End If
    'Dim reg64 As String = (Application.StartupPath() & "\data\config.reg")
    'Dim regedit As String = "regedit.exe"

    '' New ProcessStartInfo created
    'Dim p As New ProcessStartInfo
    '' Specify the location of regedit
    'p.FileName = regedit
    'p.Arguments = "/s  """ & reg64
    'Process.Start(p)
End Sub
```

Con esta rutina (que ejecuto al comienzo de la aplicación) me aseguro que mi separador decimal sea el "." y no la ",".

Pruebalo y me cuentas.

Comment: Y quiero pensar que al final le devolves los valores a lo que corresponde?

Comment: Como verás en ningún lado del código almacené los valores que tenía configurado el usuario, por ende, no lo tenía previsto. Si quieres puedes aportar esa parte del código para almacenar los valores que el usuario tenía antes de abrir el programa y devolverlos al cerrarlo.

Comment: Esto es mucho mas peligroso de lo que pensas.. q pasa si el usuario esta usando otros programas que utilicen esos valores para cosas?? que pasa si el usuario cierra mal el programa?? aunque es una solucion aceptada (no es la primera vez q la veo) es muy peligrosa. Tu codigo esta ok, es una critica constructiva al mismo, conlleva otros peligros.

Comment: Estás en lo cierto, podría afectar y agradezco tu crítica constructiva, en especial para que lo sepa quien lo lea, aunque StackOver se caracteriza por respuestas a problemas y no criticas, opiniones y demás. Gracias, igual, por el comentario/aporte. Me olvidé de comentarte: ya sufrí algo como lo que decís con los aplicativos de AFIP / I.I.B.B. que también trabajan con estos valores. Pero realmente no encuentro donde está la inoperancia. Quizás es como la facturación electrónica, que cuando quiere deja de andar.